# Spring behaviour if a java method is annotated with both @Bean and @PostConstruct

Tags: java, spring

I have the following class

```
@Configuration
public class SampleContext {

    @Bean
    @PostConstruct
    public SampleClass sampleMethod() {

    }
}
```

How does this method behave in a spring container? In which phase of the spring lifecycle does the `sampleMethod()` get called? Does it get called during the `PostConstruct` lifecycle phase when all the bean definitions are loaded and bean instances are created? If so, does the method get called again during the spring scan for `@Bean` annotations?

Update:

I have some properties present in SampleContext which I am using to initialize SampleClass bean from the sampleMethod method. If I don't use postConstruct and use only @Bean, it looks like sampleMethod() is getting called before SampleContext has initialized.

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: It seems to work but I would want to know what the behavior is going to be

Answer (score 0):

Presumably the method will be called once whilst instantiating the bean and then once more in the Post-Construct phase.